# Ball collisions js formula

Tags: javascript, physics

I understand that the collision of rectangles is calculated like this:

```
((a.y + a.height) < (b.top)) ||
(a.y > (b.y + b.height)) ||
((a.x + a.width) < b.x) ||
(a.x > (b.x + b.width))
```

I want the formula to calculate if two circles collide.

Thanks

Comment: Calculate the distance between them. Then if the distance is less than the sum of their radii, then they collide.

Comment: thanks, but shouldn't that be in the answers section?

Comment: Alright then, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // calculates distance between two points
    function distance (p0, p1) {

              var dx = p1.x - p0.x,
                  dy = p1.y - p0.y;
              return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
          }

    // if the distance between the points is less then or equal to the sum of radii 
    // it returns true i.e collision else false
    function circleCollision (c0, c1) {

              return distance(c0, c1) <= c0.radius + c1.radius;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the distance between them. Then if the distance is less than the sum of their radii, then they collide.